# Prove uniqueness of the zero of $ \frac{x}{x-1}\log\Big(\frac{x+a-1}{ax^{2}}\big)-\log\Big(\frac{b-a}{a(bx+b-1)}\Big) $

Tags: functions

I would like to prove that
$$
 f(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}\log\Big(\frac{x+a-1}{ax^{2}}\big)-\log\Big(\frac{b-a}{a(bx+b-1)}\Big)
$$

has a single zero for $x\in D=(1-a,\frac{1-a}{a})$ and $a\in (0,1)$ and $b\in(\frac{1}{2-a},1)$

Doing simulations, it appears to be the case.

I can show that there is at least one solution because $f$ is continuous on $D$ and the following:

- $\lim_{x\overset{>}{\rightarrow} 1-a}f(x) = + \infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{1-a}{a}}f(x) = 0$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{1-a}{a}}f'(x)>0$

So on $D$, $f$ starts from a positive value and reaches 0 from below at the supremum of $D$, meaning that it must have crossed the x axis at least once.

However, I could not show that the zero is unique. Trying to show that $f''$ is positive on $D$ did not yield any result.

My expression for $f'$ is:
$$
f'(x) = -\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}\log\big(\frac{x+a-1}{ax^{2}}\big)+\frac{x}{x-1}\big(-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{a+x-1}\big) + \frac{b}{bx+b-1}
$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am wondering if $f$ has a unique solution on the interval of interest. Could your simulation results be slightly off due to round off error? I am also thinking it might be the case that you have a unique solution for some values of $a$ and $b$ but not others.

Comment: @Bob: I used Mathematica to plot the function on D (using sliders for a and b) and it looks that it does have a unique solution in all cases described above. I can share my script if it's useful to you. You have indications that it is not the case?

Comment: I do not have a good reason to think it does not have a unique solution. What about trying to prove that it has a unique solution for certain special cases? Can you prove that it has a unique solution for the case of $a = 1$ and $b = 1$?

Comment: One may prove that $f'(x)=0$ has a unique solution on $D$?

Comment: @citronrose For what values of $a$ and $b$ did you find a counterexample?

Comment: @RiverLi No sorry, it does seem to be true that $f'$ has a single zero on D (but I could not prove it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ f(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}\log\bigg(\frac{x+a-1}{ax^{2}}\bigg)-\log\bigg(\frac{b-a}{a(bx+b-1)}\bigg)$$

We have
$$f'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{(x-1)^2}$$
where
$$g(x)=\frac{(1-x) (abx + 3ab - 2a+ bx - 3b - x + 2)}{(x+a - 1) (b x + b - 1)}- \log\bigg(\frac{x+a - 1}{a x^2}\bigg)$$
Then, we have
$$g'(x)=\frac{(x-1)h(x)}{x (x+a - 1)^2 (b x + b - 1)^2}$$
where
$$h(x)= b^2 x^3+(-a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^2 + 2 b -4 b^2- 1)x^2 + (-2 a- a^2 b^2  + b^2 - 2 b   + 2 a^2 b  + 2 )x -2 (a - 1)^2 (b - 1)^2$$

$$h'(x)= 3b^2 x^2+2(-a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^2 + 2 b -4 b^2- 1)x  -2 a- a^2 b^2  + b^2 - 2 b   + 2 a^2 b  + 2 $$

You already noticed

$$\lim_{x\to  1-a}f(x) = + \infty\tag1$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{1-a}{a}}f(x) = 0\tag2$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{1-a}{a}}f'(x)>0\tag3$$

Also, we can have

$$\lim_{x\to 1-a}h(x)=-(1-a)^2 (2b-ab-1)^2\lt 0\tag4$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1-a}h'(x)=-2b (1-a)^2  (2b-ab-1)\lt 0\tag5$$

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{1-a}{a}}g(x)=\frac{(2 a - 1)^2 (1-b)}{(1-a) (b - a)}\gt 0\tag6$$

$$\small\small\begin{align} &\lim_{x\to 1-a}g(x)
\\\\&=\lim_{x\to 1-a}\underbrace{\frac{1}{x+a-1}}_{\to\  +\infty}\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{(1-x) (abx + 3ab - 2a+ bx - 3b - x + 2)}{b x + b - 1}}_{\to\ a(a-1)\lt 0}-\underbrace{\frac{\log(\frac{x+a - 1}{a x^2})}{\frac{1}{x+a-1}}}_{\to\ 0}\bigg)\\\\&=-\infty\end{align}\tag7$$

Here, let us separate it into cases :

---

**Case 1** : If $\frac 12\le a\lt 1$, then we get $\frac{1-a}{a}\le 1$.

Note that $h'(x)$ is an upward parabola with $\lim_{x\to 1-a}h'(x)\lt 0$.

**Case 1-1** : If $h'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in D$, then $h(x)$ is decreasing. It follows from $\lim_{x\to 1-a}h(x)\lt 0$ that $h(x)\lt 0$. From $g'(x)\gt 0$, we see that $g(x)$ is increasing. It follows from $(6)(7)$ that $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_0$ such that $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_0$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_0\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. So, $f'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_0$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_0\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows from $(1)(2)$ that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

**Case 1-2** : If $h'(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_1$ such that $h'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_1$ and $h'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_1\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$, then $h(x)$ is decreasing for $1-a\lt x\lt x_1$ and is increasing for $x_1\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$.

**Case 1-2-1** : If $h(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in D$, then we get $g'(x)\ge 0$, so $g(x)$ is increasing. It follows from $(6)(7)$ that $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_2$ such that $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_2$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_2\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. So, $f'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_2$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_2\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows from $(1)(2)$ that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

**Case 1-2-2** : If $h(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_3$ such that $h(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_3$ and $h(x)\gt 0$ for $x_3\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$, then we see that $g'(x)\gt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_3$ and $g'(x)\lt 0$ for $x_3\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. So, $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_4$ such that $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_4$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_4\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $f'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_4$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_4\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $f(x)$ is decreasing for $1-a\lt x\lt x_4$ and is increasing for $x_4\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. Therefore, $f(x)$ has a single zero.

---

**Case 2** : If $0\lt a\lt \frac 12$, then we get $1-a\lt 1\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$.

Note that $h'(x)$ is an upward parabola with $\lim_{x\to 1-a}h'(x)\lt 0$.

**Case 2-1** : If $h'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in D$, then $h(x)$ is decreasing. It follows from $\lim_{x\to 1-a}h(x)\lt 0$ that $h(x)\lt 0$. It follows that $g'(x)\gt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt 1$ and $g'(x)\lt 0$ for $1\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_5$. So, $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_3$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_3\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $f'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_3$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_3\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. So, $f(x)$ has a single zero.

**Case 2-2** : If $h'(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_6$ such that $h'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_6$ and $h'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_6\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$, then it follows that $h(x)$ is decreasing for $1-a\lt x\lt x_4$ and is increasing for $x_4\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$.

**Case 2-2-1** : If $h(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in D$, then we get $g'(x)\gt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt 1$ and $g'(x)\lt 0$ for $1\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $g(x)$ is increasing for $1-a\lt x\lt 1$ and is dereasing for $1\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. So, $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_7$. It follows that $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_7$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_7\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. So, $f'(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_7$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ for $x_7\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

**Case 2-2-2** : If $h(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_8\lt 1$, then $h(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_8$ and $h(x)\gt 0$ for $x_8\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. Then, $g'(x)\gt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_8$ or $1\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$ and $g'(x)\lt 0$ for $x_8\lt x\lt 1$. So, it follows that $g(x)$ is increasing for $1-a\lt x\lt x_8$ or $1\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$ and is decreasing for $x_8\lt x\lt 1$. So, we see that $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_9$ such that $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_9$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_9\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

**Case 2-2-3** : If $h(x)$ has a single zero $x=1$, then $h(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt 1$ and $h(x)\gt 0$ for $1\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $g'(x)\ge 0$. So, $g(x)$ is increasing. It follows that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

**Case 2-2-4** : If $h(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_{10}\gt 1$, then $h(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_{10}$ and $h(x)\gt 0$ for $x_{10}\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$. Then, $g'(x)\gt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt 1$ or $x_{10}\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$ and $g'(x)\lt 0$ for $1\lt x\lt x_{10}$. So, it follows that $g(x)$ is increasing for $1-a\lt x\lt 1$ or $x_{10}\lt x\lt\frac{1-a}{a}$ and is decreasing for $1\lt x\lt x_{10}$. So, we see that $g(x)$ has a single zero $x=x_{11}$ such that $g(x)\lt 0$ for $1-a\lt x\lt x_{11}$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ for $x_{11}\lt x\lt \frac{1-a}{a}$. It follows that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

---

In conclusion, we can say that $f(x)$ has a single zero.

Comment: Wow, I had made a couple of steps in this direction, but I got discouraged way too soon.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To show that this zero is unique, we look at the sign of $f'(x)$.

We can rewrite $f'(x)$ as
$$
   f'(x) = \frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}\big(A(x) - B(x)\big)
 $$
where
$$
   A(x) = \frac{(1-x)\big(x(ab+b-1)-(3b-2)(1-a)\big)}{(x+a-1)(bx+b-1)}\Big)\\
$$
$$
   B(x) =  \log\big(\frac{a+x-1}{ax^{2}}\big)\nonumber
 $$
Let $x_o$ be a zero of $f'$, i.e., the position of a local extrema of $f$. We have
$$
  f(x_o) = \frac{x_o}{x_o-1}\log\big(\frac{x_o+a-1}{a x_o^{2}}\big)-\log\Big(\frac{(b-a)}{a\big(\big(b(x_o+1)-1\big)\big)}\Big)  \\
  = \frac{-x_o\big(x_o(ab+b-1)-(3b-2)(1-a)\big)}{(x_o+a-1)(bx_o+b-1)}
   -\log\Big(\frac{(b-a)}{a\big(b(x_o+1)-1\big)}\Big)
$$
The second equality holds because $f'(x_o)= 0$ by definition of $x_o$. By multiplying this last expression by $(bx_o+b-1)$, which is positive, we can then define a new function $h(x)$
whose sign is the same as the sign of $f(x)$ for $x=x_o$.

$$
 h(x) = C(x)-D(x)\,,
$$
where
$$
  C(x) = \frac{-x\big(x(ab+b-1)-(3b-2)(1-a)\big)}{(x+a-1)}
$$
$$
  D(x) = (bx+b-1)\log\Big(\frac{(b-a)}{a\big(bx+b-1\big)}\Big)
$$
We can now compute the second derivatives of $C(x)$ and $D(x)$.
$$
  C'(x) = -\frac{\big(2x(ab+b-1)-(3b-2)(1-a)\big)(x+a-1)}{(x+a-1)^{2}}
   + \frac{x^{2}(ab+b-1)-x(3b-2)(1-a)}{(x+a-1)^{2}}\\
  =  -\frac{x^{2}(ab+b-1)-2x(1-a)(ab+b-1)+(3b-2)(1-a)^{2}}{(x+a-1)^{2}}
$$
$$
  C''(x) = - \frac{\big(2x(ab+b-1)-2(1-a)(ab+b-1)\big)(x+a-1)}{(x+a-1)^{3}} +
  \frac{2\big(x^{2}(ab+b-1)-2x(1-a)(ab+b-1)+(3b-2)(1-a)^{2}\big)}{(x+a-1)^{3}}\nonumber\\
  = -\frac{2(1-a)^{2}(ab-2b+1)}{(x+a-1)^{3}} > 0 \quad \forall b>\frac{1}{2-a}
$$
$$
  D'(x) = b\log\big(\frac{b-a}{a}\big) -b\big(\log(bx+b-1)+1\big) \quad
  D''(x) = -\frac{b^{2}}{bx+b-1} <0 \quad \forall x\in D \nonumber
$$

Hence
$$
h''(x) = C''(x)-D''(x) <0  \quad \forall x \in D, \forall b > \frac{1}{2-a}
$$
This means that $h$ is convex, so there cannot be three points in D $x_{1}<x_{2}<x_{3}$ such that $0>h(x_{1})<h(x_{2})>0>h(x_{3})$.
Hence the same can be said of three zeros of $f'$, so $f(x)$ cannot have more that one zero.